# How would a test case test for an exception?

Tags: java, testing

For my code I have:

```java
public void addContact(Contact contact) {
  if (contact == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("contact must not be null");
  }
  this.contacts.add(contact);
}
```

And for my test case I have:

```java
@Test

public void testForAddEmptyContact() {
  Contact nullContact = null;
  assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
    testContactList.addContact(nullContact);
  });
}
```

When I run the code in program, the code after "assertThrows" is red.

Comment: JUnit 5, right?

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I think `NullPointerException` would be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: I tried in IntelliJ with JUnit 5.4 and a bare minimum of "boilerplate" and the test passed just like it should. Then I changed the exception thrown by `addContact()` and the test failed just like it should. In the test, `assertThrows()` is underlined with a red dotted line. That's just IntelliJ's way of telling me where the test failed.

Comment: Could you clarify the problem? Apparently everything is normal as Alonso has stated.